# Return Graphql Count

Tags: graphql

I have this Graphql query

```
 "{TABLE_NAME{
    id
    severity
    des
    ip
    hostname
    description

  }
}";
```

That's return over 1000 records, how to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

in Graphql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you dont. A GraphQL object type does not necessarily map 1:1 to a database table so you cannot look at it that way. If you want to get a count from a table, you need to add that as either a field to your output type or as its own field. I assume since you want to find out how large a table is before you query it you want a 'tableInfo' type query which would look like

```
const TableInfo = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'TableInfo',
  fields: {
    count: GraphQLInt
  }
})
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    tableInfo: {
      type: TableInfo,
      args: {
        name: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
      },
      resolve (source, args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          connection.query(
            'SELECT COUNT(*) from ' + args.name,
            (error, results) => {
              return error ? reject(error) : resolve(results)
            }
          )
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: Query
})
```

then request with

```
query Info {
  tableInfo(name: "my_table") {
    count
  }
}
```

that said, this is not a good pattern and if you are expecting a query to return a large amount of results you should instead use pagination. Best practices are here http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

```
query {
  posts {
    meta {
      pagination {
        total
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where **posts** is the name of your *collection*

source = https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was a really good idea.  In my case I had to modify it to ```query { 
  accounts { 
    totalCount
    }
  }```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use:

```
query {
    listOfElts (first: 1) { 
        totalCount 
    }
}
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Comment: @LordWilmore It just works nicely in my GitHub graphql call, which successfully retrieve the numbers of repositories that I have. Sometimes we just want a simple answer is enough. It seems there are not much to explain here.